# Storage for multiple sets of 100k rows, each with 100 numeric values, filter/paging/sort capabilities; any db, sql/nosql or any Azure's service needed

Tags: sql, database, azure, nosql

I have multiple sets of data, each with less than 100K rows, each row with ~100 numbers (floating point).

Need to choose storage for this data, with import and querying capability. Import happens only once, after that data is not changed.

Following queries should execute quickly (pseudo-sql used):

```
SKIP 60 rows, 
SELECT ALL COLUMNS, 30 next rows
WHERE column1 BETWEEN A and B
ORDER BY column6 ASC/DESC
```

Query always includes paging and ordering; filtering (where) is optional. Filtering (if included) happens only using one column and always has form `A < x < B`

We currently use Cosmos (former DocumentDB) and it's too expensive.

Please suggest a cheaper alternative.

It is also possible to remove some requirements for querying (e.g. no filtering), if it's not compatible with your suggestion.

Comment: Unfortunately this is off-topic: service recommendation and opinion-solicitation. And you're talking about pricing. There's simply no right answer to this.

Comment: @DavidMakogon Unfortunately, this is just your opinion. In reality, this question perfectly aligns with https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic since it (1) `covers software tools, commonly used by programmers` and (2) `is a practical, answerable problem that is unique to software development`

Comment: Nope - nothing to do with my opinion - your question is *very* broad. And you're asking for a "cheaper alternative" - that's about service pricing. Off topic. Type of database? Off-topic (graph? column? k/v? document? relational?). It's broad, opinion-based, and service-recommendation. That's three off-topic reasons. And you've already garnered an opinion-piece on relational databases (with a bunch of brand names thrown in). And this is why these questions are off-topic: they lead only to opinion and spam.

Comment: And from that same link of what's [on-topic vs off-topic](stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic): *Questions which are too broad, unclear, incomplete or primarily opinion-based may be put on hold by the community until they are improved.*

Comment: @DavidMakogon I am working on very specific storage problem, that is very strictly defined: 100K rows of 100 floating point numbers with paging/filtering/sorting capabilities, insert once, no updates. Why did you decide the question is `broad` ?

Comment: It's broad because there are many ways to solve this. And with your limited requirements, nearly any database will do. Anyway - this is the last I'll say on this. I've explained this beyond where I should need to. The question doesn't fit.

Comment: @DavidMakogon requirements are not "limited". They are **strict** (thus, not broad). The fact, that there are multiple ways to implement them, does not mean that question is bad and does not fit. Even if you feel requirements are not pretty well defined, let me clarify them for you, by asking questions, rather than saying "this is broad and bad".

Comment: @DavidMakogon I have given a re-thought to this. If you feel I should remove the question, just let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You could easily run this on a free database and depending on how many datasets you have this would fit on a medium to high spec personal computer or a small server.  Each dataset will be between 40MB and 80MB depending on whether the numbers are integers or floating point or decimal.  It will take a bit more space when it is in a database.

I would use a relational database because you are dealing with numbers rather than text or documents.  PostgreSQL or MySQL would work.  SQLite would be OK depending on how many datasets you have.  I'd prefer PostgreSQL or MySQL because they really are full function databases.  A little more information, including links to download sites, is here: http://www.thedatastudio.net/relational_databases_you_can_use.htm.

Comment: Does your idea imply creating index on each column? Did you count the space for that index? Is indexing required?

Comment: With tables this size, indexing is probably a disadvantage.  Queries on these tables will run really fast without indexes.  I say that without seeing the data, because you will get several of these datasets in memory and a full scan will take no time, whereas loading 100 indexes would take time.

Comment: I notice that you say the numbers are floating point, I missed that before.  In this case you definitely do not want to index them because you will almost never get an exact match.

Comment: I don't know whether you have 10 or 10 million datasets.  If you have 10 million then you should look at SciDB <http://www.paradigm4.com/try_scidb/>.  I don't have experience of this, but  it is specialised for scientific data.

Comment: Those datasets will come and go dynamically, so in an ideal case the solution should scale indefinitely, however, there will never be cross-dataset queries.

Comment: Please don't answer such off-topic questions. And making a blanket statement of "choose a relational database" isn't a valid answer. Or more accurately, is just as valid as "choose a document database." And just naming relational database brands? Again, not an answer.